# Node.js database result return late inside the function

Tags: node.js

Node.js database result return late inside the function

const db = req.app.db;

```
function getFeaturebyID(featureids) {
    db.planFeatures.findOne({"_id": featureids }).then(features => {
        return features.planFeaturesTitle;
    });
  }

const planLists ={};
db.planManagement.find({}).toArray((err, planList) => {

// res.end(JSON.stringify(planList));
featurearray = [];
    var j =1;
    planList.forEach(function(row) {
        planLists._id = row._id;
        features = row.planFeatures.split(',');

        for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        featurearray[i] = getFeaturebyID(features[i]);
        // console.log(getFeaturebyID(features[i]));
        }
        //row.planFeaturesName[j] = featurearray;
        console.log(featurearray);
        j++;
      });
     //console.log(planList); 

//  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.session));

    res.render('stylist/plan_selection', {
        top_results: planList,
        title: 'Schedule',
        config: req.app.config,
        session: req.session,
        message: common.clearSessionValue(req.session, 'message'),
        messageType: common.clearSessionValue(req.session, 'messageType'),
        helpers: req.handlebars.helpers,
        showFooter: 'showFooter'
    });


});
```

});

return features.planFeaturesTitle; return a value late while calling the function. I try callback but not works

Comment: Can you give more details on the issue you're seeing? adding some logs to your code that illustrate what's going on and adding some description of what you expected vs what's actually happening will make it much easier to help you

Comment: please explain your problem properly, try to do it 3 steps, 1. problem statement, 2. code related it(only what is imp.), 3. expected and actual output

Answer (score 0):

This is due to asynchronous nature of node.js,

First declare your function async like this,

```
const getFeaturebyID = async (featureids) => {
    const features = await db.planFeatures.findOne({"_id": featureids });
    return features.planFeaturesTitle;
}
```

Then use it like this,

```
planList.forEach(async (row) => {
    // your code here
    for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        featurearray[i] = await getFeaturebyID(features[i]);
    }
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Not working properly

planList.forEach(async (row) => {
            features = row.planFeatures.split(',');
            console.log(j);
            if(j == 1){
            for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
            //featurearray[i] = await getFeaturebyID(features[i]);
            }
            }
            console.log(j);
            j++;
          });
four records in database
j print before await
1
1
1
1
j print after await
1
2
3
4